# Trying to upload VM (Ubuntu Server) to AWS EC2. ERROR: image not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have followed all the steps in AWS's documentation to the letter, but am getting this "ERROR: image not found" when I try to upload via CLI (I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks in the terminal). I exported the VM from VMware Workstation and saved it as an OVF file. Here is my command for the EC2 CLI:

```
ec2-import-instance /Users/CrimKid/AWS_EC2/ec2-api-tools-1.7.5.1/UbuntuAWS.ova -f OVA -t t2.medium -a x86_64 -b my-import -o crimkid -w (secret_key) -p Ubuntu_Server -O (access_key_ID) -W (Secret_Access_Key) --private-ip-address 192.168.1.26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image was bad. Once I recreated it with another machine I was able to upload it to AWS.